# LocalJumpError: no block given (yield) rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to  try this helper method in rails console, but I get an error
I'm sorry I'm a newbie en rails

```
juan:~/workspace/sample_app$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0.beta2)
2.1.1 :001 > helper.provide(:title,"Home")
 => nil 
2.1.1 :002 > yield :title
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

I want to reproduce the behavior in rails console of the view helper method called provide

Example

```
 <% provide(:title, "Home") %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sample App</h1>
    <p>
      This is the home page for the
      <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
      sample application.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *I need to try this helper method in rails console,* Can you explain why you need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yield` only when you are inside a method which has been called with a block. In the rails console, you are in the main environment and without any block which is why you get that error.

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630621/how-does-the-yield-magic-work-in-actionview) to find out how `yield` works in the view.

The best way to do what you're trying to do is to put a debugger inside the view while its rendering and then test out the provided functionality.